# Why JavaScript rather than a standard browser virtual machine?

Tags: javascript

Would it not make sense to support a set of languages (Java, Python, Ruby, etc.) by way of a standardized virtual machine hosted in the browser rather than requiring the use of a specialized language -- really, a specialized paradigm -- for client scripting only?

To clarify the suggestion, a web page would contain byte code instead of any higher-level language like JavaScript.

I understand the pragmatic reality that JavaScript is simply what we have to work with now due to evolutionary reasons, but I'm thinking more about the long term.  With regard to backward compatibility, there's no reason that inline JavaScript could not be simultaneously supported for a period of time and of course JavaScript could be one of the languages supported by the browser virtual machine.

Comment: I don't know why this is getting voted down. I thought it was a good question!

Comment: Because it's more of a complaint than a question.

Comment: It's due to the idea that javascript isn't a real language, or isn't as good as other languages.  Neither of these have been true since the early days, yet the 'dirty' perception presently persists.

Comment: Sounds like a JS hater question/comment. I love JS so I see no need to support other languages. I can't wait to start using node.js and do all of my web development in this dirty language.

Comment: Wow, I have never seen the SO community fail so completely. The only answers that even address the idea proposed here are all the way to the bottom, getting downvoted, while the answers needlessly "defending JS" are getting all the love. This question doesn't attack JS, it is merely advocating choice. It's simply saying: "whatever you may think of JS, wouldn't it be nice to be able to use some other languages as well if you prefer them?". What is wrong with you?

Comment: It's ok, the poster accepted an answer - essentially confirming he was trolling. It's a shame the interesting question was missed.

Comment: I think Google's Native Client project (http://code.google.com/p/nativeclient/) is fascinating in this regard.  Almost all the speed and flexibility of native code, with all the security of Javascript.  Definitely a possible taste of things to come.

Comment: This is a major problem with StackOverflow allowing for edits so far into the future after several answers have been provided. The original question asked is more relevant to the top answers, while the rest address the "new spirit" of the question after the edits.

Comment: Aren't plug-ins (e.g. Silverlight, Flash) the workarounds which directly address what's being proposed here? And if users think it's a good idea, they'll choose to install it, rather than having it forced upon them.

Comment: Because there is a strong status quo bias for javascript. Most of the people here will continue, instead of answering the question, to defend javascript to the death even though switching to a VM will not affect them in any way. The plain fact of the matter is that there aren't really any good reasons for it. The lack of any real answers demonstrates that clearly.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Well, yes. Certainly if we had a time machine, going back and ensuring a lot of the Javascript features were designed differently would be a major pastime (that, and ensuring the people who designed IE's CSS engine never went into IT). But it's not going to happen, and we're stuck with it now.

I suspect, in time, it will become the "Machine language" for the web, with other better designed languages and APIs compile down to it (and cater for different runtime engine foibles).

I don't think, however, any of these "better designed languages" will be Java, Python or Ruby. Javascript is, despite the ability to be used elsewhere, a Web application scripting language. Given that use case, we can do better than any of those languages.

Comment: -1 for the IE CSS team remark. IE6 wasn't bad when it was released, it's main competitor was the buggiest piece of crap software that has ever been written. Person attacks, although somtimes fun, don't make the world a better place.

Comment: Couldn't disagree with your assessment of JavaScript as "...a Web application scripting language..." less. It's a great, flexible language with a lot more applicability than that.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: ITYM "Couldn't disagree [...] more."?

Comment: @Jaroslaw Szpilewski Shameless JS zealotism? Did you miscomment on this, thinking it another post? Also, for @erikkallen, the IE CSS team comment was what's commonly known as "a joke".

Comment: Some "clairvoyance" in this answer: we now have CoffeeScript.

Answer (score 20):

I think JavaScript is a good language, but I would love to have a choice when developing client-side web applications. For legacy reasons we're stuck with JavaScript, but there are projects and ideas looking for changing that scenario:

1. [Google Native Client](http://code.google.com/p/nativeclient/): technology for running native code in the browser.
2. [Emscripten](http://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/): LLVM bytecode compiler to javascript. Allows LLVM languages to run in the browser.
3. Idea: .NET CLI in the browser, by the creator of Mono: http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2010/May-03.html

I think we will have JavaScript for a long time, but that will change sooner or later. There are so many developers willing to use other languages in the browser.

Comment: LLVM could be an answer to all of this. There are already a big number of languanges (Python, Ruby, even Java) with support for compiling to LLVM, and LLVM can compile to Javascript, so at the very least we could get automatic LLVM support in browsers simply by compiling to JS.

Of course LLVM can't be optimized for all programming paradigms and specific languages, so performance won't be the same as 100% native, but Javascript's JITs/Interpreters, even taking into account recent advances, have always been slow relative to native anyway.

Answer (score 18):

Answering the *question* - No, it would not make sense.

Currently the closest things we have to a multi-language VM are the JVM and the CLR. These aren't exactly lightweight beasts, and it would not make sense to try and embed something of this size and complexity in a browser.

Let's examine the idea that you could write a new, multilanguage VM that would be better than the existing solution.

- You're behind on stability.
- You're behind on complexity (way, way, behind because you're trying to generalize over multiple languages)
- You're behind on adoption

So, no, it doesn't make sense.

Remember, in order to support these languages you're going to have to strip down their APIs something fierce, chopping out any parts that don't make sense in the context of a browser script. There are a huge number of design decisions to be made here, and a huge opportunity for error.

In terms of functionality, we're probably only *really* working with the DOM anyway, so this is really an issue of syntax and language idom, at which point it does make sense to ask, "Is this really worth it?"

Bearing in mind, the *only* thing we're talking about is client side scripting, because server side scripting is already available in whatever language you like. It's a relatively small programming arena and so the benefit of bringing multiple languages in is questionable.

What languages would it make sense to bring in? (Warning, subjective material follows)

Bringing in a language like C doesn't make sense because it's made for working with metal, and in a browser there isn't much metal really available.

Bringing in a language like Java doesn't make sense because the best thing about it is the APIs anyway.

Bringing in a language like Ruby or Lisp doesn't make sense because JavaScript is a powerful dynamic language very close to Scheme.

Finally, what browser maker really wants to support DOM integration for multiple languages? Each implementation will have its own specific bugs. We've already walked through fire dealing with differences between MS Javascript and Mozilla Javascript and now we want to multiply that pain five or six-fold?

It doesn't make sense.

Comment: Quite a subjective answer, but I didn't want to vote down as you raise some good points (and the original answer is more like discussion starter anyway).

Comment: I don't think the VM in browser is necessary to heavy. Of course it already exists as Silverlight and Applets. The latter failed to gain popularity, I think mostly because of bad timing and technical stupidities which are mostly resolved. Allowing any language between the script tag (with restrictions) would be pretty cool, and certainly not impossible nor unpractical.

Comment: Heaviness (MB)? Probably okay. Heaviness (complexity)? *Way* too heavy. Any multi-language VM you have, you will have language implementations sitting on top (eg. JRuby/IronRuby, Clojure, Jython/IronPython), etc. Either the JVM eats the complexity or the language implementers do.

Comment: It would take a staggering amount of work to re-implement multiple languages for multiple brand new platforms (IE/Firefox/Safari...). And languages change, too. "This page only visible in a Ruby 1.9 browser"? Please, no.

Comment: As an alternative language for web-scripting; I'd actually think something very like Ada would make a lot of sense. (Very strong typing, packages, generics, tasks -- and each of these can be nested in any of the others.) If we're talking the 2012 revision, then we get pre- and post-conditions, null exclusions, static & dynamic predicates.

Comment: I don't think you're answering the question properly, you are only stating why you think other languages aren't suited for what javascript does in the browser at this moment. A universal bytecode suited for the web would be something other languages compile into, if that language is useful would be up to its creator not the web-bytecode, many languages already do this btw by compiling into javascript (ie, dart).

Comment: I think you misunderstand the question, most if not all browsers already use a VM, some compile js to VM and then VM to assembly.
making a VM for the web would not require making a client-side parser for every language you want to support, it would require only making a VM and if a server wants to send some byte code to the client it would send code in the VM, not in lua/java/c etc...
the browser maker would not need to make DOM integration for multiple languages.

Answer (score 14):

On Windows, you can register other languages with the Scripting Host and have them available to IE. For example VBScript is supported out of the box (though it has never gained much popularity as it is for most purposes even worse than JavaScript).

The Python win32 extensions allowed one to add Python to IE like this quite easily, but it wasn't really a good idea as Python is quite difficult to sandbox: many language features expose enough implementation hooks to allow a supposedly-restricted application to break out.

It is a problem in general that the more complexity you add to a net-facing application like the browser, the greater likelihood of security problems. A bunch of new languages would certainly fit that description, and these are new languages that are also still developing fast.

JavaScript is an ugly language, but through careful use of a selective subset of features, and support from suitable object libraries, it can generally be made fairly tolerable. It seems incremental, practical additions to JavaScript are the only way web scripting is likely to move on.

Answer (score 12):

I would definitely welcome a standard language independent VM in browsers (I would prefer to code in a statically typed language).

(Technically) It's quite doable gradually: first one major browser supports it and server has the possibility to either send bytecode if current request is from compatible browser or translate the code to JavaScript and send plain-text JavaScript.

There already exist some experimental languages that compile to JavaScript, but having a defined VM would (maybe) allow for better performance.

I admit that the "standard" part would be quite tricky, though. Also there would be conflicts between language features (eg. static vs. dynamic typing) concerning the library (assuming the new thing would use same library). Therefore I don't think it's gonna happen (soon).

Answer (score 10):

If you feel like you are getting your hands dirty, then you have either been brainwashed, or are still feeling the after affects of the "DHTML years". JavaScript is very powerful, and is suited well for its purpose, which is to script interactivity client side. This is why JavaScript 2.0 got such a bad rap. I mean, why packages, interfaces, classes, and the like, when those are clearly aspects of server-side languages. JavaScript is just fine as a prototype-based language, without being full-blown object oriented.

If there is a lack of seamlessness to your applications because the server-side and client-side are not communicating well, then you might want to reconsider how you architect your applications. I have worked with extremely robust Web sites and Web applications, and I have never once said, "Hmm, I really wish JavaScript could do (xyz)." If it could do that, then it wouldn't be JavaScript -- it would be ActionScript or AIR or Silverlight. I don't need that, and neither do most developers. Those are nice technologies, but they try to solve a problem with a technology, not a... well, a solution.

Comment: How can you say, that JavaScript isn't full-blown object oriented? It's certainly one of the most object-oriented languages that I know of. Everything in JavaScript is an object - even functions. It's just that OOP in JavaScript doesn't look like OOP in many other languages.

Comment: OOP is not inherent to JavaScript. You don't have packages, interfaces, abstract classes, or method overloading built into the core, and you can't extend an object -- only an object's prototype, which makes it technically prototype-based, not OOP based.

Comment: Dead wrong on that one. "Protype" is a Design Pattern (Gamma et. al., pp 117 - 126). As you'll recall Design Patterns revolve around common designs in Object Oriented Programming. And just because the language doesn't have the same features as other OOP languages doesn't mean it isn't OOP.

Comment: That would not make me "dead wrong", and it would simply open up the strict definition of OOP to interpretation - e.g. - how much of JavaScript is OO based. My answer: "Some of it - the rest is prototype based."

Comment: You're not dead wrong, I think the best way to put it is that JS is not class based OO, it's prototypal OO.

Comment: 1. Javascript is fully OOP. OOP is about objects, not about classes. 2. You can extend an object in JavaScript, that's the whole point of Prototypal object oriented programming. 3. You're not answering the question, the question is not attacking JS, is just asking for choice. I think JS is a great language, but I would love to have other choices when programming in the browser.

Comment: Dustman, defining design patterns as patterns that emerge from strictly from OOP is ignorant at best and dishonest at worst.

Comment: Manuel, just because JavaScript has objects does not mean it fits the classical definition of OOP. It is missing a few key components -- abstract and concrete classes, as well as interfaces. A prototype is basically a copy of an object, not a class template, and you're not subclassing, your extending an object's prototype.

Comment: @hal1001:  JavaScript, Java, Ruby, SmallTalk, ActionScript, etc all support the object-oriented programing paradigm.  Some of them allow object inheritance via prototypes, while others use classes (ActionScript supports both).  "Prototypal" and "class-based" are just names for two inheritance/instantiation schemes a language can provide for its objects.

Comment: @Brian Reindel "packages, interfaces, abstract classes, or method overloading" are not OOP. Just because you can do OOP with classes it doesn't mean you need them (OOP pattern was invented in a procedural language) and just because classes are also used for many other things, it doesn't mean those things are OOP. Inheritance is not OOP, it is a feature of class based programming, or maybe a pattern of code reusability. That said, **JavaScript does have inheritance** and constructors which represent classes and you can have your class methods and properties in the prototype of the constructor.

Comment: @BrianReindel You seem to be misusing the word "classical" here. The term "classical OOP" refers to a type of OOP that uses classes. In this case, "classical" means "having classes," not "orthodox." A language doesn't have to involve classes or interfaces in order to be OOP, and JavaScript is absolutely an object-oriented language.

Comment: 1. JS is absolutely object oriented, maybe not to the same extent as other languages but it still is OOP.

2. he's not asking for a way to do more things, he's asking for the option to use byte code/VM (which is what browsers actually run) instead of JS.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think that a standard web VM is that inconceivable. There are a number of ways you could introduce a new web VM standard gracefully and with full legacy support, as long as you ensure that any VM bytecode format you use can be quickly decompiled into javascript, and that the resulting output will be reasonably efficient (I would even go so far as to guess that a smart decompiler would probably generate better javascript than any javascript a human could produce themselves).

With this property, any web VM format could be easily decompiled either on the server (fast), on the client (slow, but possible in cases where you have limited control of the server), or could be pre-generated and loaded dynamically by either the client or the server (fastest) for browsers that don’t natively support the new standard.

Those browsers that DO natively support the new standard would benefit from increased speed of the runtime for web vm based apps. On top of that, if browsers base their legacy javascript engines on the web vm standard (i.e. parsing javascript into the web vm standard and then running it), then they don’t have to manage two runtimes, but that’s up to the browser vendor.

Answer (score 6):

While Javascript is the only well-supported scripting language you can control the page directly from, Flash has some very nice features for bigger programs. Lately it has a JIT and can also generate bytecode on the fly (check out [runtime expression evaluation](http://www.sephiroth.it/weblog/archives/2008/04/runtime_expression_evaluation_in_acti.php) for an example where they use flash to compile user-input math expressions all the way to native binary). The Haxe language gives you static typing with inference and with the bytecode generation abilities you could implement almost any runtime system of your choice.

Comment: What am I missing with the question? It seems Flash would do exactly what he wants. We're not talking about another native language, he wants a VM, right? Good answer.

Answer (score 6):

Quick update on this old question.

Everyone who affirmed that a "web page would contain byte code instead of any higher-level language like JavaScript" "won't happen".

June 2015 the [W3C](https://www.w3.org/community/webassembly/) announced [WebAssembly](https://webassembly.github.io) that is

> a new portable, size- and load-time-efficient format suitable for
>   compilation to the web.

This is still experimental, but there is already some prototypal implementation in Firefox nightly and Chrome Canary and there is already [some demonstration working](https://webassembly.github.io/demo/).

Currently, WebAssembly is mostly designed to be produced from C/C++, however

> [as WebAssembly evolves it will support more languages than C/C++, and we hope that other compilers will support it as well](https://github.com/WebAssembly/design/blob/master/FAQ.md#is-webassembly-only-for-cc-programmers).

I let you have a closer look at the [official page](https://webassembly.github.io) of the project, it is truly exciting!

Answer (score 5):

this question resurfaces regularly. my stance on this is:

**A) wont happen** and **B) is already here.**

pardon, what? let me explain:

#### ad A

a VM is not just some sort of universal magical device. most VMs are optimized for a certain language and certain language features. take the JRE/Java (or LLVM): optimized for static typing, and there are definitely problems and downsides when implementing dynamic typing or other things java didn't support in the first place.

so, the "general multipurpose VM" that supports lots of language features (tail call optimization, static & dynamic typing, foo bar boo, ...) would be colossal, hard to implement and probably harder to optimize to get good performance out of it. but i'm no language designer or vm guru, maybe i'm wrong: it's actually pretty easy, only nobody had the idea yet? hrm, hrm.

#### ad B

already here: there may not be a bytecode compiler/vm, but you don't actually need one. afaik javascript is turing complete, so it should be possible to either:

1. create a translator from language X to javascript (e.g. coffeescript)
2. create a interpreter in javascript that interprets language X (e.g. [brainfuck](http://www.google.at/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=javascript+brainfuck+interpreter)). yes, performance would be abysmal, but hey, can't have everything.

#### ad C

what? there wasn't a point C in the first place!? because there isn't ... yet. google NACL. if anyone can do it, it's google. as soon google gets it working, your problems are solved. only, uh, it may never work, i don't know. the last time i read about it there were some unsolved security problems of the *really* tricky kind.

---

**apart from that:**

- javascript's been there since ~1995 = 15 years. still, browser implementations differ today (although at least it's not insufferable anymore). so, if you start something new yet, you might have a version working cross browser around 2035. at least a working subset. that only differs subtly. and needs compatibility libs and layers. no point in not trying to improve things though.
- also, what about readable source code? i know a lot of companies would prefer not to serve their code as "kind-of" open source. personally, i'm pretty happy i'm able to read the source if i suspect something fishy or want to learn from it. hooray for source code!

Answer (score 4):

There are some errors in your reasoning.

1. A standard virtual machine in a standard browser will never be standard.  We have 4 browsers, and IE has conflicting interests with regard to 'standard'.  The three others are evolving fast but adoption rate of new technologies is slow.  What about browsers on phones, small devices, ...
2. The integration of JS in the different browsers and its past history leads you to under-estimating the power of JS.  You pledge a standard, but disapprove JS because standard didn't work out in the early years.
3. As told by others, JS is not the same as AIR/.NET/... and the  like.  JS in its current incarnation perfectly fits its goals.

In the long term, Perl and Ruby could well replace javascript.  Yet the adoption of those languages is slow and it is known that they will never take over JS.

Answer (score 4):

Indeed. Silverlight is effectively just that - a client side .Net based VM.

Answer (score 3):

How do you define best? Best for the browser, or best for the developer? (Plus ECMAScript is different than Javascript, but that is a technicality.)

I find that JavaScript can be powerful and elegant at the same time. Unfortunately most developers I have met treat it like a necessary evil instead of a real programming language.

Some of the features I enjoy are:

- treating functions as first class citizens
- being able to add and remove functions to any object at any time (not useful much but mind blowing when it is)
- it is a dynamic language.

It's fun to deal with and it is established. Enjoy it while it is around because while it may not be the "best" for client scripting it is certainly pleasant.

I do agree it is frustrating when making dynamic pages because of browser incompatibilities, but that can be mitigated by UI libraries. That should not be held against JavaScript itself anymore than Swing should be held against Java.

Comment: +1 - Lets not confuse language issues with browser interpretation of the code.

Comment: why should you defend JS, when he simply asked for a bytecode choice?

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript is the browser's standard virtual machine. For instance, OCaml and Haskell now both have compilers that can output JavaScript. The limitation is not JavaScript the language, the limitation is the browser objects accessible via JavaScript, and the access control model used to ensure you can safely run JavaScript without compromising your machine. The current access controls are so poor, that JavaScript is only allowed very limited access to browser objects for safety reasons. The Harmony project is looking to fix that.

Answer (score 3):

It's a cool idea. Why not take it a step further?

- Write the HTML parser and layout engine (all the complicated bits in the browser, really) in the same VM language
- Publish the engine to the web
- Serve the page with a declaration of which layout engine to use, and its URL

Then we can add features to browsers without having to push new browsers out to every client - the relevant new bits would be loaded dynamically from the web. We could also publish new versions of HTML without all the ridiculous complexity of maintaining backwards compatibility with everything that's ever worked in a browser - compatibility is the responsibility of the page author. We also get to experiment with markup languages other than HTML. And, of course, we can write fancy JIT compilers into the engines, so that you can script your webpages in any language you want.

Comment: I can't tell if you're kidding, but your idea is actually really cool.

Answer (score 3):

I would welcome any language besides javascript as possible scripting language.

What would be cool is to use other languages then Javascript. Java would probably not be a great fit between the  tag but languages like Haskell, Clojure, Scala, Ruby, Groovy would be beneficial.

I came a cross Rubyscript somewhile ago  ... 
http://almaer.com/blog/running-ruby-in-the-browser-via-script-typetextruby and http://code.google.com/p/ruby-in-browser/
Still experimental and in progress, but looks promising.
For .Net I just found: http://www.silverlight.net/learn/dynamic-languages/ Just found the site out, but looks interesting too. Works even from my [Apple Mac](http://ironpython.net/browser/examples/mushroom/).

Don't know how good the above work in providing an alternative for Javascript, but it looks pretty cool at first glance. Potentially, this would allow one to use any Java or .Net framework natively from the browser - within the browser's sandbox.

As for safety, if the language runs inside the JVM (or .Net engine for that matter), the VM will take care of security so we don't have to worry about that - at least not more then we should for anything that runs inside the browser.

Answer (score 2):

Probably, but to do so we'd need to get the major browsers to support them. IE support would be the hardest to get. JavaScript is used because it is the only thing you can count on being available.

Answer (score 2):

The vast majority of the devs I've spoken to about ECMAScript et. al. end up admitting that the problem isn't the scripting language, it's the ridiculous HTML DOM that it exposes. Conflating the DOM and the scripting language is a common source of pain and frustration regarding ECMAScript. Also, don't forget, IIS can use JScript for server-side scripting, and things like Rhino allow you to build free-standing apps in ECMAScript. Try working in one of these environments with ECMAScript for a while, and see if your opinion changes.

This kind of despair has been going around for some time. I'd suggest you edit this to include, or repost with, specific issues. You may be pleasantly surprised by some of the relief you get.

A old site, but still a great place to start: [Douglas Crockford's site](http://javascript.crockford.com).

Comment: i'd be curious to hear more about why the "HTML DOM" is the pain point

Answer (score 2):

Well, we have already VBScript, don't we? Wait, only IE supports it!
Same for your nice idea of VM. What if I script my page using Lua, and your browser doesn't have the parser to convert it to bytecode? Of course, we could imagine a script tag accepting a file of bytecode, that even would be quite efficient.
But experience shows it is hard to bring something new to the Web: it would take years to adopt a radical new change like this. How many browsers support SVG or CSS3?

Beside, I don't see what you find "dirty" in JS. It can be ugly if coded by amateurs, propagating bad practice copied elsewhere, but masters shown it can be an elegant language too. A bit like Perl: often looks like an obfuscated language, but can be made perfectly readable.

Answer (score 2):

Check this out http://www.visitmix.com/Labs/Gestalt/ - lets you use python or ruby, as long as the user has silverlight installed.

Comment: "as long as the user has silverlight installed." well, I can see a flaw in this one.

Comment: To be honest, it's probably easier to do that than getting Ruby embedded into ie6/7/8/9/ff/chrome/safari. Heck Chrome already includes flash, why not SL!

Answer (score 2):

This is a very good question.

It's not the problem only in JS, as it is in the lack of good free IDEs for developing larger programs in JS. I know only one that is free: Eclipse. The other good one is Microsoft's Visual Studio, but not free.

Why would it be free? If web browser vendors want to replace desktop apps with online apps (and they want) then they have to give us, the programmers, good dev tools. You can't make 50,000 lines of JavaScript using a simple text editor, JSLint and built-in Google Chrome  debugger. Unless you're a macohist.

When Borland made an IDE for Turbo Pascal 4.0 in 1987, it was a revolution in programming. 24 years have passed since. Shamefully, in the year 2011 many programmers still don't use code completion, syntax checking and proper debuggers. Probably because there are so few  good IDEs.

It's in the interest of web browser vendors to make proper (FREE) tools for programmers if they want us to build applications with which they can fight Windows, Linux, MacOS, iOS, Symbian, etc.

Comment: Visual studio is free, and you also have vs code, Atom, and other great IDEs, I think you just aren't looking hard enough

Answer (score 1):

Realistically, Javascript is the only language that any browsers will use for a long time, so while it would be very nice to use other languages, I can't see it happening.

This "standardised VM" you talk of would be very large and would need to be adopted by all major browsers, and most sites would just continue using Javascript anyway since it's more suited to websites than many other browsers.

You would have to sandbox each programming language in this VM and reduce the amount of access each language has to the system, requiring a lot of changes in the languages and removal or reimplementation of many features. Whereas Javascript already has this in mind, and has done a for a long time.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're looking for Google's Native Client.

Answer (score 1):

In a sense, having a more expressive language like Javascript in the browser instead of something more general like Java bytecode has meant a more open web.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is **not so easy** issue. We can say that we're stuck with JS, but is it really so bad with jQuery, Prototype, scriptaculous, MooTools, and all fantastic libraries?

Remember, JS is **lightweight**, even more so with V8, TraceMonkey, SquirrelFish - new Javascript engines used in modern browsers.

It is also **proved** - yeah, we know it has problems, but we have lots of these sorted out, like early security problems. Imaging allowing your browser to run Ruby code, or anything else. Security sandbox would have to be done for scratch. And you know what? Python folks already **failed** two times at it.

I think Javascript is going to be **revised and improved** over time, just like HTML and CSS is. The process may be long, but not everything is possible in this world.

Comment: well, to my knowledge, every security check done for the JS sandbox can (and usually is) done on the byte code as checking permissions and such things by looking at a bunch of text is hard for a computer to do.
sending byte code to the client instead of standard JS shouldn't change that

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you "understand the pragmatic issue that JavaScript is simply what we have to work with now". Actually it is very powerful language. You had your Java applet in browser for years, and where is it now?

Anyhow, you don't need to "get dirty" to work on client. For example, try GWT.

Answer (score 0):

... you mean...

Java and Java applet
Flash and Adobe AIR
etc..

In general, any RIA framework can fill your needs; but for every one there's a price to pay for using it ( ej. runtime avalible on browser or/and propietary or/and less options than pure desktop )
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_rich_internet_application_frameworks

For developing Web with any non-web languaje, you've GWT: develop Java, compile to Javascript

Comment: Hence the suggestion to standardize a VM so it would be ubiquitous.  Using JavaScript as a "machine language for the web" seems incredibly clunky and inefficient.

Comment: I think you misunderstand, the original poster is not suggesting that browsers should support other languages, he is suggesting that instead of compiling java to js, you would compile java into a VM.

Answer (score 0):

Because they all have VMs with bytecode interpreters already, and the bytecode is all different too. {Chakra(IE), Firefox (SpiderMonkey), Safari (SquirrelFish), Opera(Carakan).

Sorry , I think Chrome (V8) compiles down to IA32 machine code.

Answer (score 0):

well, considering all browsers already use a VM, I don't think it will be that difficult to make a VM language for the web.
I think it would greatly help for a few reasons:
1. since the server compiles the code, the amount of data sent is smaller and the client doesn't waist time on compiling the code.
2. since the server can compile the code in preparation and store it, unlike the client which tries to waist as little time quickly compiling the JS, it can make better code optimizations.
3. compiling a language to byte code is way easier then transpiling to JS.

as a final note (as someone already said in another comment), HTML and CSS compile down to a simpler language, not sure if it counts as byte code, but you could also send compiled html and css from the server to the client which would reduce parse and fetch times

Answer (score -1):

IMO, JavaScript, the language, is not the problem. JavaScript is actually quite an expressive and powerful language. I think it gets a bad rep because it's not got classical OO features, but for me the more I go with the prototypal groove, the more I like it.

The problem as I see it is the flaky and inconsistent implementations across the many browsers we are forced to support on the web. JavaScript libraries like jQuery go a long way towards mitigating that dirty feeling.

Answer (score -2):

JavaScript is your only native, standard option available.  If you want lots of power, grab jQuery, but if you need to do a bunch more, consider writing an addon for Firefox? or similar for IE etc.

Comment: What do you mean by "power"? jQuery is slow as hell, undescifrable and has bad practice written all over it. It doesn't even resemeble a programming language. And the question is about programming languages, not frameworks written with programming languages.

Answer (score -3):

So what you'd have done with all those Pythons and Rubys in the browser?!

1). Still writing scripted client-side apps? Well, this is nicely done with JavaScript.

2). Writing client-server apps using sockets? Why don't write them just without browser?

3). Writing standalone apps? Just do it as you do now.